# Object is returned the same although I'm mutating it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

The upcoming code snippet is removing the password attribute from the user JSON object and return it in response. what is happening is that the password attribute is still returning!

```
const signin = (req, res, next) => {
    let requestBody = req.body;

    userModel.findUserByEmail(requestBody.email).then(user => {
        bcrypt.compare(requestBody.password, user.password, (error, result) => {
            if (!result) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    status: false,
                    message: 'Auth Failed!',
                    error
                });
            }

            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error
                });
            }

            let token = jwt.sign({
                email: user.email,
                userId: user._id
            }, 
            process.env.JWT_KEY, 
            {
                expiresIn: "2h"
            });

            // remonve password key
            delete user.password

            res.status(200).json({
                status: true,
                message: 'Authenticated!',
                data: {
                    token,
                    user
                }
            });
        });

    }).catch(error => {
        return res.status(500).json({
                status: false,
                message: 'Auth Failed!',
                error
            });
    });
}
```

not sure the problem is related to async compilation or not

Comment: I think you are supposed to delete the elements like this: delete user['password']

Comment: Instead of using `delete user.password;` use `Reflect.deleteProperty(user, "password");` then check if it returns `true`.

Comment: Above two comments are incorrect, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). Asker's usage of delete is correct, the problem is probably code not shown.

Comment: @Klaycon what's incorrect about determining whether or not a property is actually deleted?

Comment: @zfrisch `delete user.password` will also return `true` if the property is absolutely no longer on the object and `false` otherwise, having to use Reflect is wholly unnecessary and verbose

Comment: @Klaycon Hm. You're right. The literal text on it states **Returns A Boolean indicating whether or not the property was successfully deleted.**, and I guess that mislead me to believe it had... you know, accuracy, over `delete` ? lol. Though it does have the benefit of TypeErrors. One step in the right direction for the spec, but definitely a letdown.

Comment: The snippet shown should work.  You could confirm via a console log that the user object is as expected before being returned in the response.  Which would imply the error is elsewhere.

Comment: the object user is returned from mongoose find query, I tested the delete method with another normal object via console and the results did well. but here can't see any action on user, does it because a special status in mongoose returned object or an async code exec.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new object without the password and use that in your response:

```js
const { password, ...restOfUser } = user

res.status(200).json({
  status: true,
  message: 'Authenticated!',
  data: {
    token
    user: restOfUser
  }
})
```

Comment: A very clever use of destructuring.  Will have to remember that one for copying most, but not all properties from an object.